# compute sphere cap from outer volume of two sphere intersection

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spheres

I am trying to compute the distance AB as in the following schema  representing the intersection of two spheres, knowing the value of the green volume.
[image: intersecting spheres]

I have based my solution on the sphere cap formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Volume_and_surface_area), using this notation:

$V_g$: green volume

$a$ : the distance AB, which is the variable I am trying to solve for

$V_d$: cap volume corresponding to AH

$V_s$ : cap volume corresponding to AG

$h_s$ : the distance AG

$h_d$ : the distance AH

$r$ the radius of the small circle: CD

$R$ the radius of the big circle: OE

We obtain the following equations:

$V_g = V_d - V_s$

$ V_d = \frac{\pi}{6} * h_d * (3*a^2 + h_d^2)$

$ V_s = \frac{\pi}{6}* h_s * (3*a^2 + h_s^2) $

However, $h_s$ and $h_d$ also depends on a as:

$ h_s = R - R*cos(sin_{-1}(a))$ by applying trigonometry to the triangle ABO

$ h_d = r - \sqrt{r^2 - a^2}$ by applying trigonometry to the triangle CAB

Which leads me to this equation:

$ V_g * \frac{6}{\pi} = h_d*(3*a^2 + h_d^{2}) - h_s*(3*a^2+h_s^{2}) $

$h_s$ and $h_d$ being dependent on $a$, I struggle to solve the inverse function like $a = f(V_g)$, is it possible to solve this kind of equation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=OB,r=CB$ be the radii of the spheres, $d=OC$ the distance between centers.

Let $b=AC$, then Pythagoras' in right triangles $\triangle ACB, \triangle AOB$ gives:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
AB^2 = CB^2-CA^2 = OB^2-OA^2 \implies r^2 - b^2 &= R^2 - (d+b)^2
\\ r^2 - \cancel{b^2} &= R^2 - d^2 - 2bd - \cancel{b^2}
\\ b &= \frac{R^2-r^2 - d^2}{2d} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

The heights of the caps in the two spheres are $AH = r - b\,$, $AG = R - d - b\,$, so the green volume is:

$$
V_g = \frac{\pi AH^2}{3}\left(3 r - AH\right) - \frac{\pi AG^2}{3}\left(3R - AG\right) \tag{2}
$$

Equation $(2)$ is an algebraic equation in $R, r, d$ which can be solved for one unknown if the other two are given. Once $d$ is determined, $b$ follows from $(1)$, then $a = \sqrt{r^2 - b^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what i am searching for, i do not know yet the value of d and b, and want to make them dependant of the green volume, however it pointed me to a mistake i made in posing my problem which might need more known parameters, i will update my question with details if i can find the answer

Comment: @CorentinSalomon Assuming $V_g$ is given, you'll also need to know two of $R,r,d$ in order to solve $(2)$ for the remaining unknown.